# scaling 4:3 points to 16:9 points

Tags: c#, .net, aspect-ratio

I have an array of points which all range from x(0-512) and y(0-384) which means an aspect ratio of 4:3.

If I want to display every points, perfectly, on a 16:9 monitor, what math would be needed to achieve this?

Let's say "ee" is my 4:3 point and "point" is the 16:9 point I need..

I thought since I'm trying to scale it on a 1920:1080 monitor, which is a 16:9 aspect ratio

```
point = new PointF(ee.x * (1920 / 512), ee.y * (1080 / 384));
```

But this seems to be off by abit.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with `perfectly`? Fill the entire 16:9 monitor which ruins the aspect ratio (a circle will turn to an egg), or preserve the aspect ratio and accept black vertical bars to the left and right of the 3:4 image?

Comment: Make sure you use floats then cause here in integer `1920 / 512 = 3` and `1080 / 382 = 2`... just do `1920.0` and `1080.0`

Answer (score 1):

You can't match *exactly* the aspect other than by multiplying each dimension by an integer. Here the only integer that would fit is 2 (cause 384 * 3 > 1080)...

so you would have to do:

```
point = new Point (ee.x * 2, ee.y * 2);
```

and you could center it with:

```
point = new Point (ee.x * 2 + ((1920 - 512*2)/2), ee.y * 2 + ((1080 - 384*2)/2)));
```

Hope that helps...

Edit: with floats, you have to take the minimum of the multiplier:

```
var multiplier = Math.Min(1920.0/512, 1080.0/384);
point = new Point (ee.x * multiplier + ((1920 - 512*multiplier)/2), ee.y * multiplier + ((1080 - 384*multiplier)/2)));
```

Comment: I'm so sorry.. I forgot to say PointF instead of Point. I accept float values also.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate what you mean by "off"?

If you mean that the image looks stretched horizontally, it is because the aspect ratio is larger than before. If you want the image to look like what it was before (but bigger), you'll need to scale one axis by the aspect ratio to fix it.

```
aspect_ratio_before = 4.0f / 3.0f;
aspect_ratio_after = 16.0f / 9.0f;

// This is equal to 4/3.
aspect_ratio_difference = aspect_ratio_after / aspect_ratio_before;

// I squish the X axis here.
point.x /= aspect_ratio_difference;

// Alternatively, you can also multiply point.y by the 
// aspect_ratio_difference, though that will stretch the Y axis instead.
// Use only one!
// point.y *= aspect_ratio_difference;
```

Disclaimer: I have not worked with .net before, so I don't know all the details of its rendering engine. This is based off my experience working with OpenGL and scaling.